# Factoring $x^2+4$ [Elementary]

Tags: factoring

The real factors of $ x^2+4$ are:

How to factor this without being complex?

Comment: $x^2+4$. Are you sure you didn't mean $x^4+4$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Have! It's from AHSME 1950

Comment: Google finds an answer to your problem quite quickly:  https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1950_AHSME_Problems#Problem_15

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change its meaning after you have received an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  we have $$x^2+4=x^2\color{blue}{+4x}+4\color{blue}{-4x}=(x+2)^2-(2\sqrt{x})^2$$
which can be factored as a difference of squares.

The answer would be

> $$x^2+4=(x-2\sqrt{x}+2)(x+2\sqrt{x}+2)$$

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what the OP is asking. If $\sqrt x$ is allowed I could go on and "factorize" $x+2 - 2\sqrt x = (\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt 2 x^{1/4}) (\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt 2 x^{1/4})$

Answer (score 1):

The factorization of a polynomial in monic binomials is unique. As $x^2+4=(x+2i)(x-2i)$, there is no other option.

Comment: Downvoters, please consider cancelling. I am not responsible for the OP's mistakes.